# How would one say "Unite/unify and conquer"?

Tags: vocabulary

We all know the principle of divide and conquer: *divide et impera*

I was wondering (kind of as a joke) what would be the appropriate translation of "unite and conquer" or "unify and conquer" (whichever one sounds better)?

Comment: Cf. Benjamin Franklin's "join or die" -- or in Latin "iungite aut perite"-- along with the image of a cut up rattlesnake to emphasize the dangers disunity among the American colonies. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join,_or_Die

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several different ways, but I prefer *conduc et impera*. *Conducere* is one of the many words which can mean "unite," but in this particular case, it's also used for gathering together troops:

> 1. Of persons (esp. freq. of the collecting, assembling of troops in any place): milites de castellis ad castra, Sisenn. ap. Non. p. 514, 7: “populum in forum,” Varr. ib. p. 274, 20: “exercitum in unum locum,” Caes. B. G. 2, 2: “eo copias omnes,” id. B. C. 3, 13 fin.: “copias suas,” id. B. G. 6, 31 init.; cf. “auxilia,” Liv. 30, 21, 3; 23, 13, 8: “dispersas suorum copias,” Tac. H. 4, 71: “virgines unum in locum,” Cic. Inv. 2, 1, 3: “omnis clientes suos eodem,” Caes. B. G. 1, 4: “milites in unum,” Sall. J. 51, 3; cf. Tac. A. 4, 47.—

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't really make it clear, but I was referring to uniting the enemy. As in, "let's help out enemies unite and then go about conquering them". I know this is nonsensical, but the absurdity is precisely what I wanted to bring out.

Comment: Yes, that still works. Unlike the English *unite*, *conducere* is transitive, so it has to have an object. "Unite [them] and conquer." It's going to be ambiguous either way, though, so perhaps you could make the object explicit: *Conduc hostes et supera*, "unite the enemies and conquer."